# How to decrypt a crypted message in a String in Java

Tags: java, string, cryptography

I have to write a program which, inserted a crypted string, returns the sum of the letters after a " * ".
I know that i have to take the character before the " * " but i don't know how to configure the substring and how complete the code. The space should be printed as is, without changes.
The example is in the code due to not supported characters.

This is my code.

Example:

String in input (possibile also in more lines)

```
dfdf*Hwwqqw*efgftfg*ldsdsd*lwewwe*o eerrr*mwqqwq*ujk*mjfrem*mert*yfg
     ^      ^       ^      ^      ^       ^      ^   ^      ^    ^
```

Output of the program: `Hello mummy`

---

```
public class Decrypt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String word = s.nextLine();
            String[] temp = word.split("\\*");

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temp));

        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You neither explained how your encryption works, nor your code does anything related to encryption/decryption. I am guessing that `dfdf` is encrypted character `H` - how?

Comment: I apologise, i only have to ignore the characters before the "*". This is my crittography :)

Comment: mummy cannot be found, there is mistakes

Comment: There was an error, now the example should be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply achieve that by capturing the pattern and replace it, the pattern is :

1. some characters `\w*`
2. a star `\*`
3. the char you need  `.` **: capture it `(.)`**
4. some characters `\w*`

then keep capture 2

```
String str = "dfdf*Hwwqqw*efgftfg*ldsdsd*lwewwe*o eerrr*mwqqwq*ujk*mjfrem*mert*yfg";
String decrypt = str.replaceAll("\\w*\\*(.)\\w*", "$1");
System.out.println(decrypt);
```

---

- [***Working Demo***](https://ideone.com/zGpaRH)
- [***Regex Demo***](https://regex101.com/r/DnKYB0/3)

Comment: The error was mine again. However, how did you do to set the regex?

Comment: @Lory "How" ,  in what sense ? Because I know about regex I would say

Comment: A nice regex answer. Often other people post only the code.

Comment: @Lory I changed the regex be careful, I remove the useless capturing group `()` so now it's $1 and not $2 with the new regex

Answer (score 1):

you can also try the same

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

     String s = "dfdf*Hwwqqw*efgftfg*ldsdsd*lwewwe*o eerrr*mwqqwq*ujk*mjfrem*mert*yfg";

     String a[] = s.split("\\*");
     StringBuilder b =  new StringBuilder("");
     for ( String newS : a )
     {
         b = b.append(newS.charAt(0));
     }
     b.replace(0,1, "");
     System.out.println(b);
}
```